# I am learning C and can't figure out why this is giving me an error

Tags: c, function

So I am trying to write a function that receives a float value, returns a float value, and is displayed in main with printf. I keep getting the same errors:
markup2.c:58: error: conflicting types for ‘GetPrice’
markup2.c:46: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘GetPrice’ was here

Where am I making the mistake? I've tried typecasting everything that touches GetPrice but still no luck. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

```
    #include<stdio.h>

// define the constant MARKUP as float value 0.1
#define MARKUP 0.1

int main()
{
    // declare variables
    char proceed;
    float value;
    float markupValue;

    // display welcome message to user and inform them of markup rate
    printf("\nThank you for using Chad Hammond's markup calculator.\n");
    printf("The current markup rate is %.1f%c.\n",MARKUP*100,'%');

    // ask user if they want to perform a markup
    printf("Would you like to markup an item? y/n:\n");
    scanf("%c", &proceed);

    // if yes, proceed to next step
    if(proceed == 'y')
    {
        // prompt user for the price of item to be marked up
        printf("Please enter a wholesale value to markup: ");
        scanf("%f", &value);

        // display input back to user
        printf("The wholesale value you entered was: %c%.2f\n",'$', value);
        markupValue = (value*MARKUP);

        // display amount of increase
        printf("The dollar amount of this increase will be: %c%.2f\n",'$', markupValue);

        // display total price after increse
        printf("The price for this item after markup is: %c%.2f\n",'$', (float)GetPrice(value));
    }else
        // if user did not want to markup an item, belittle them with sarcasm
        printf("Well, if you didn't want to markup an item you should have just used a Ti-83 and left me alone!\n\n");
    // display exit message
    printf("Thank you for using HammondInstruments Markup Calculator, goodbye.\n");

    // return that program has completed
    return 0;
}

float GetPrice(float value)
{
    float output;
    value += value*MARKUP;
    output = value;
    return (float)output;
}
```

Comment: compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o markup markup.c` and you will see the error :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to either declare or define `GetPrice` before your `main`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I'm used to Java where you can have a method before or after main and it runs fine. Glad it was such a simple mistake, I've been scratching my head for hours trying to see how the logic was incorrect in my function! Thank you all!

Comment: yeah, this one is pretty specific to C. Since you mentioned about Java, I would also point out that unlike Java, it is considered a good practice in C to declare all your variables in the beginning of your function (which you have followed). Also, could you please "accept" my answer?

Comment: @DeepanjanMazumdar, Not just good practice. It used to be required.

Answer (score 3):

C expects to see its functions before you can use them (forward declaration). You've used `GetPrice` in `main` before declaring it (the function definition is after `main`).

When your compiler sees the use of `GetPrice`, it assumes that it's a function it hasn't seen yet and generates an *implicit* declaration, which looks like `int GetPrice()`. Later on, when it sees the function declaration, it sees that the real function signature differs from the implicit declaration, and throws an error.

The solution, therefore, is to either define `GetPrice` before `main`, or use a *forward declaration* of the form `float GetPrice(float);` before `main`. The forward declaration (like what is actually found in the various header files you `#include`) tells the compiler the function exists, but leaves its definition to later (or even to another file).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, it makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you first declare `GetPrice` ? And then `main` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that since you didn't declare one before `main`, the compiler is giving you a default declaration of `GetPrice` that doesn't match yours, thus the conflict. You should add a prototype before `main`, or move the entire function there:

```
float GetPrice(float);
//main
float GetPrice(float value){...}
```

or

```
float GetPrice(float value){...}
//main
```